# results from $wpdb->last_query

Tags: php, wordpress

I am attempting to move a single page into Wordpress as a plugin as an Admin menu. I first verify that isset($wpdb) but my test query fails. I do $wpdb->last_query and I don't understand the results.

This is what I try:

```
    $clientquery = $wpdb->query("select post_title from wp_posts where id=390");
    exit(var_dump( $wpdb->last_query));
```

This is the result:

> ```
> string(44) "select post_title from wp_posts where id=390"
> ```

Where is string(44) coming from?  BTW, I am absolutely new to developing in PHP and Wordpress learning this on my own.

Also, if I change the query to "select * from ..." the result changes to string(35)... . What?

Comment: it is the type of the variable, a string of 44 characters

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for something dramatic and completely overlooked the character count. In the end, I must still continue trying to find out why even such a simple query fails.

Comment: I can't tell by the information you gave, there are many things that could've gone wrong but use these pages as reference:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php, there are many examples on the bottom that can help you

Answer (score 1):

assuming you have declared $wpdb as a global the above should work so your code should look like this:

```
global $wpdb;
$clientquery = $wpdb->query("select post_title from wp_posts where id=390");
var_dump($clientquery);
```

note the results are stored in $clientquery

Comment: Thanks David. Mauricio's comment told me what string(44) meant got me to stop thinking the query was the problem. I could then see I had a typo when I was testing the $clientquery for results. I copied the same typo into my var_dump($clientquery) and since that had no results I resorted to $wpdb->last_query and I did not understand what it was telling me. Things are working and I am displaying data.

Answer (score 1):

The `$wpdb->last_query` shows the exact MySQL Query itself and `string(44)` indicates that it is string type of length 44:

```
 string(44)   select post_title from wp_posts where id=390
```

WordPress defines a class called wpdb, which contains a set of functions used to interact with a database. Its primary purpose is to provide an interface with the WordPress database, but can be used to communicate with any other appropriate database. So it is not necessary to check using `isset()` function